# How to import variable labels from Excel into Stata

Tags: excel, stata

I have a Excel-sheet, which contains variable and variable-labels. I would like to import this file into Stata. How can I do it?

Comment: Much depends on the details, but you could read it in as a dataset containing variable names and variable labels as string variables, convert it to a do file and then run it alongside your main dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your variable names are on the first row, and labels on the second row.

I would do:

```
import excel using file.xlsx, firstrow clear

foreach var of varlist _all {
   local x = `var'[1]
   label var `var' "`x'"
   }
drop if [_n]==1
foreach var of varlist _all {
   cap destring `var', replace
   }
```

The first bit replaces the label of the variables with the variable label, which should be in the first row of your imported dataset. The second bit drops this row, and the destrings all variables for which this is possible without an error. The reason for this is that all variables will be imported as strings when you have the second row as variable labels.

This is the most typical case I encountered, but of course there may be other scenarios where you have to adopt different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer did not work for me. Assume you have the names of your variables in the first row of your Excel file, and the labels in the second row. The script below works for me:

```
import excel yourexcelfilehere, clear allstring
foreach var of varlist * {
    local row1 = `var'[1]
    local row2 = `var'[2]
    label var `var' "`row2'"
    local vn = strtoname("`row1'")
    rename `var' `vn'
}
drop in 1/2
destring, replace
```

EDIT NJC Alternative code -- according to taste -- and you could go further in cutting out local macros used.

```
    import excel yourexcelfilehere, clear allstring
    foreach var of varlist * {
        label var `var' "`= `var'[2]'"
        local vn = strtoname("`= `var'[1]'")
        rename `var' `vn'
    }
    drop in 1/2
    destring, replace
```

Comment: By all means use the local macros if you think they make the code clearer,but you don't need them. I've edited your answer to show alternative code because it's fiddly to show it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I like your alternative version